# Access a user entity reference in a commerce-product template file

Tags: 8, entities, commerce

I have a *field_intervenant*field which contains a user entity reference.
In the commerce-product template file, I want to access the description field of each intervenant.

How can I achieve it?

I tried reading the following values, but none of them returns what I am looking for.

- `product.field_intervenants.entity.field_description`
- `product.field_intervenants.0.entity.field_description`
- `product_entity.field_intervenants.0.entity.field_description`
- `product_entity.field_intervenants.field_description`
- `product_entity.field_intervenants.field_description.value`

Do I need to loop through it, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a loop, as the referenced entity fields returns an array, you can see an example here and adjust it by you own needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291698/drupal-8-twig-entity-reference-sub-fields-templating